# Add Table to DataClass without Associations

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datacontext

I'm using Linq on a third part database and I have DataContext that contains all my tables I've used so far. I'm trying to add another table and have run into what I think is a database design issue, but I can't change the DB.

There are two tables, JobOperations and JobOperationsTime. JobOperations.Job_Operation is a KeyNum(int) that is nullable. JobOperationsTime.Job_Operations is foreign key KeyNum(int) that is not nullable.

When I drag and drop JobOperationsTime onto the DataContext, I get an error of:

The parent property JobOperation.Job_Operation1 does not match the child property JobOperationTime.Job_Operation. The parent property cannot be nullable if the child property is not nullable.

Is there anyway to force this table into the DataContext without this association?

I can't change the database so I'm stuck here. My objective is to be able to write linq queries against these tables and replace the current SQL queries.

Comment: Do you mean that `JobOperations` has a nullable primary key?

Comment: Gert Arnold - No JobOperations has a different field called JobOperationKey that is the PK and obviously it's non nullable. The field JobOperations.Job_Operations1 is just a field and is nullable in this table. The matching field in the other table is also not a PK but is not nullable.